# Combine and return the result in SQL based on null checks

Tags: sql

I have a table with columns t1(c1,c2,c3), at any point of time each row of the table will have only one column will be populated and rest will be null.
Example, R1(xyz, null, null), R2(null, null, abc) where R1 and R2 are rows.
I want to right a query to return xyz for R1, abc for R2....

I could think of is this,

```
select concat(c1,concat(c2,c3)) as end_result from t1;
```

Are there any other solutions possible?

Comment: `coalesce(c1, c2, c3)` will give the first non-null value.

Comment: coalesce worked for my requirement precisely thanks.